# How to use MySQL fulltext to search for phrases instead of using LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search

How to use mysql fulltext search to search for phrases instead of like :

```
SELECT description FROM t WHERE info LIKE "%Search phrase one%" OR  info LIKE "%Phrase second%"  OR info LIKE "%Another phrase with more words%"
```

Comment: look up the docs for MATCH() and AGAINST().

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample query for searching phrases:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH ( col1,col2,col3 ) 
AGAINST ('"some words" "another phrase"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

More infos at : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Why `'"word1" "word2" "word3"'` and not just `'word1 word2 word3'`?