# MySQL - MATCH Keywords with Spaces AGAINST Large Text

Tags: mysql, regex, match-against

We have a keyword database, for example:

```
1 | MySQL
2 | Database Developer
3 | Software Engineer
4 | Director of Development
```

And we need a fast way to scan a large set of text (say a resume in base text) to match these exact words, with spaces.

Granted, most of the text we're scanning is well over 1,000 characters, it could be something like:

```
I am a Senior Software Engineer with Director of Development experience specializing in JavaScript, JSON, and Web Development. I also have Management experience and have worked in Banking, Cloud, and custom CRM development environments. I am also familiar with .NET and Kittens.
```

But they need to be exact matches; for example we want "Director of Development" to match, and not "Director" or "Development" by themselves.

Right now we are using REGEXP like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    sit_keyword sk
WHERE
    @large_resume_text REGEXP CONCAT('\\b',sk.keyword,'\\b');
```

It works fine, but it's very slow, and has issues with + and -. But it works - matching the FULL TEXT of the keyword and not just pieces of it.

However, the fastest way to do this would be to use MATCH AGAINST. Note the sit_keyword table has a FULLTEXT index.

e.g.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    sit_keyword sk
WHERE
    MATCH(sk.keyword) AGAINST (@large_resume_text);
```

The problem is the MATCH AGAINST system breaks the words from the MATCH(*col1*) up into separate words. For example "Software Engineer" will return a match against the text if either word "Software" or "Engineer" is in the AGAINST target. Even if we put quotes around the col1 keywords, it's the same. This is causing our MATCH AGAINST to pull out keywords that are not true matches.

How can we force MATCH AGAINST to match the entire MATCH(*col1*) value against the target text, and not the individual words in *col1*?

Comment: Can't you just use `WHERE x = y` or `WHERE x LIKE '%'+y+'%'` if you want partial full matches?

Comment: @ctwheels x = y requires an exact match and doesn't work against 1,000 characters. LIKE "works" but it's slow - VERY slow - compared to MATCH AGAINST. M/A is hands down the fastest way to do this - I just need to figure out how to match combined words rather than chunks.

Comment: Try either [How to use MySQL fulltext to search for phrases instead of using LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3908697) or [MySQL fulltext search - Only results that contain all words](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2282679) (probably the first link, but it's not 100% clear from your question).

Comment: @Solarflare unfortunately, neither link answers the question, which is how to get the engine to use the "total word value" of the MATCH column against a large (1,000+ character) set of text.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE MATCH(resume) AGAINST ("+Director +Development" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND resume LIKE "%Director of Development%"
```

Notes:

- Remove words shorter than the min word length established for your FULLTEXT index.
- Remove any "stop" words (eg, `the`)
- Put `+` on other words.
- The `MATCH` should be fast, but (as you say) not adequate.  Add the `LIKE` to filter out the rest.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a solution as the AGAINST text is 1000+ words from a resume. I cannot control or define the +/- terms. Technically I could do WHERE @resume_text LIKE '%Keyword%'; -- and that works - but it's not nearly as fast as MATCH AGAINST.

Comment: There are probably propriety solutions for searching resumes.

Comment: possibly; but I at least want to get an efficient search system working on our end. Digging deep into MATCH AGAINST it seems to be a poorly designed system that has no real-world application of truly processing natural language. All of the examples from ORACLE are not real-world applications (such as comparing keywords against a resume or contents of a book page). As mentioned REGEXP works just fine, it's just slow... so slow...

Comment: What drives me nuts is there appears to be no way to tell the engine to MATCH the PHRASE (e.g. "Hello World") AGAINST a target; this would solve the problem. Instead it always matches each word, and doesn't seem to provide a workaround. Even if you quote "Hello World" it still matches both Hello and World... GRR.

Comment: @Floobinator - A phrase that is enclosed within double quote (“"”) characters matches only rows that contain the phrase literally, as it was typed. -- I'm pretty sure that means double quotes; single quotes can be around the whole string:  `AGAINST('"blue socks" "red dress"')`

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: the problem is I need to match a keyword database entry (e.g. MATCH(col1) where col1 is the keyword) AGAINST the large text. Sadly, MATCH AGAINST doesn't allow the use/definition of Keywords in the AGAINST part. I tried putting the long text of MATCH in a database table column, but I couldn't then take 1000 characters of text and MATCH it against a database of 700+ keywords. The system simply didn't allow it. If you're aware of a way to do this, that could solve my problem. I wasn't able to get it to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239740/discussion-between-floobinator-and-rick-james).